# Qt - remove substring from QString

Tags: c++, qt, unicode, utf-8

In my project in Qt , I have specific string ""dsfsd we rrh erh er￼[image]"". I want to remove ￼￼￼￼￼￼all substring like this :
￼[image]
 and keep other string.

```
QString messageText = m_messageEdit->toPlainText();
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: You have a memory leak in that code: You allocate memory and assing a pointer to the memory to `msg_char but directly overwrite that pointer with a pointer to `messageText.data()` making you lose the original pointer to the memory you allocated.

Comment: As for the errors, they are pretty clear, if you only read them through. To start with, `QChar` is not `char` on your system.

Comment: Please write what exactly you want to remove from string (note that in edit mode those characters are invisible and in question they look incorrectly)? Why you are converting to utf8 if you just want to remove something? Best way to operate on `QTextEdit` is `QTextDocument` and `QTextCursor`! Chain of conversions to `QString` and utf8 is quite costly.

Comment: I can barely parse the question. What's the deal with all that Unicode nonsense? Can't you simplify the question?

Answer (score 2):

The errors are so clear:

1. QChar* is diferent to char*. That means that `char *msg_char = new QChar[k];`is not valid, it should be something like `QChar *msg_char = new QChar[k];` or else declare a char* and then pass it to QChar*
2. Same here but with in `msg_char = messageText.data();`. Your `messageText.data();`returns a QChar*, not a char*
3. Same here, it complains about msg_char is not what it expects for the fromAscii (counting that you didn't forced the code)
4. `QString str = QString::fromUtf8 (messageText);` remove the space between fromUsf8 and (  and be sure about the type of `messageText`. Then you can try too with `messageText.toStdString()` You have a lot of functions like .toStdString() or .toAscii() or .toLatin1() ...

If you are using c++11 and have problems with the types, you can use the type `auto`:

```
auto *msg_char = new QChar[k];
```

And then print the type of msg_char and you will see the type.

Remember that QString and std::string are diferent things so you use QString::fromUtf8() with QString and string.toUtf8(). for std::string and same with QChar and char (The QSomething are classes from Qt and the others are from c++)

**Edit:** why did you changed all the full question??? Isn't it easier for you and other users to do another one or delete it so the comments ans answers still fit with the question??

What you need is to see the `std::string` library and search there its functions and methods: [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) Here you have all you need with easy to understand examples

Answer (score 1):

If your aim is only converting to utf8, simply way is using std::string

```
QString var = "Hello World";
std::string varUtf8 = var.toUtf8().constData();
```

If your unreadle char is always at the end, you can remove them using substr;

```
std::string var =var.substr(0, str.length()-1);
```

or you can use `std::string.erase();`

Comment: I want to remove unreadable sub string.